# Is it possible to get browser to cache OPTIONS result

Tags: http, cors

I am trying to get the user's browser to stop making OPTIONS request once it learns that my api server allows for cross origin requests but it doesn't seem like adding the standard headers effects it. Is it possible to do this?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization,Content-Type,Request,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://example.com
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 13 Aug 2015 18:25:42 GMT
Expires:Fri, 12 Aug 2016 18:25:42 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2:

> 9.2 OPTIONS
>   […]
>   Responses to this method are not cacheable.

Comment: Thanks! That seems unfortunate from a performance tuning perspective.